# Microsoft Speech Recognition with Custom Speech Protocol (Xamarin Android, Websocket)

Tags: c#, websocket, xamarin.android, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to build a continuous speech recognition from microphone using the Microsoft Cognitive Speech for Xamarin Android. I don't think there is library for Xamarin. The documentation are : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol

I already done the websocket connection thing, now I am pretty stuck on sending the message to the websocket server. I noticed on the documentation that

> We have to send **Headers** on a specific **Path** everytime we send a **Message**

for e.g these headers are to set up the first configuration for speech protocol,

```
Path : speech.config
X-Timestamp :   Client UTC clock time stamp in ISO 8601 format
Content-Type :  application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I am using **WebSocketClient** but I don't find any way to set up headers or change path. Is there any way to set up the headers and/or changing path so I can send message properly to the server? Or do I have a wrong perception?

My second problem is **WebSocketClient** doesnt have any event handler to receive message, what I do is :

```
private static async Task DataReceiving(ClientWebSocket ws)
{
while (true)
{
   ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
   WebSocketReceiveResult result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(
   bytesReceived, CancellationToken.None);
   Log.Info("SOCKETRECEIVED",Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count));
   if (ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
   {
       Log.Info("SOCKETCLOSED", "CLOSED");
       break;
   }
}
}
```

but I did not receive any message or anything.

**EDIT :**

Here is my code for **Headers**,

```
//List<Tuple<string, string>> Headers <<Contains [Title] and [Content]
foreach (var item in Headers)
{
    message += item.Item1 + " : " + item.Item2 + Environment.NewLine;
}
message += Environment.Newline; // ensure double carriage return
```

**EDIT :**
Here is my code for sending WAV Header :

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    short channelCount = 1;
    int sampleRate = 1024;
    int bitsPerSample = 16;
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {


        writer.Write("Path: audio"+Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("X-Timestamp: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"+Environment.NewLine));
        writer.Write("Content-Type : audio/x-wav"+Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("X-RequestId: " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-",string.Empty)+Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);

        //chunk ID
        writer.Write('R');
        writer.Write('I');
        writer.Write('F');
        writer.Write('F');

        writer.Write(-1); // -1 - Unknown size

        //format
        writer.Write('W');
        writer.Write('A');
        writer.Write('V');
        writer.Write('E');

        //subchunk 1 ID
        writer.Write('f');
        writer.Write('m');
        writer.Write('t');
        writer.Write(' ');

        writer.Write(16); //subchunk 1 (fmt) size
        writer.Write((short)1); //PCM audio format

        writer.Write((short)channelCount);
        writer.Write(sampleRate);
        writer.Write(sampleRate * 2);
        writer.Write((short)2); //block align
        writer.Write((short)bitsPerSample);

        //subchunk 2 ID
        writer.Write('d');
        writer.Write('a');
        writer.Write('t');
        writer.Write('a');

        //subchunk 2 (data) size
        writer.Write(-1); // -1 - Unknown size
    }
    byte[] result;
    //using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    //{
    //    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    //    result = ms.ToArray();
    //}
    result = stream.ToArray();
    ArraySegment<byte> byteresult = new ArraySegment<byte>(result);
    await _socketclient.SendAsync(byteresult, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, CancellationToken.None);
    Log.Info("SENDINGWAV", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
}
```

Here is my code for Sending data byte,

```
public async Task SendByteHeader(byte[] data)
{
        string s = "";
        s+=("Path: audio" + Environment.NewLine);
        s +=("X-Timestamp: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ" + Environment.NewLine));
        s +=("Content-Type : audio/x-wav" + Environment.NewLine);
        s +=("X-RequestId: " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine);
        s +=(Environment.NewLine);
        byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        List<byte> endres = new List<byte>(array);
        endres.AddRange(data);

        ArraySegment<byte> byteresult = new ArraySegment<byte>(endres.ToArray());
        await _socketclient.SendAsync(byteresult, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, CancellationToken.None);
        Log.Info("SENDINGBYTE", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
  }
```

I run this on the start of connection :

```
Task.Run(()=>DataReceiving(_socketclient));
```

So, I sent Wav header first, then start sending audio byte from recording ( I am using Plugin.AudioRecording). 
I still haven't got any message / response yet.

**EDIT** :

I sent some data to the server every 200 ms to make it "real time", but i noticed that after 5-6 sending, all of my SendAsync got **crash** on this code :

```
await _socketclient.SendAsync(byteresult, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, CancellationToken.None);
```

The error is "Cannot access disposable object (the websocket)) ". It seems the websocket got disposed? Or the connection got terminated?

Comment: can you share your (github gist) code some part of code where you are connecting with websockets, sending headers, sending audio data and then receiving response from server. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using WebSocketClient but I don't find any way to set up headers or change path. Is there any way to set up the headers and/or changing path so I can send message properly to the server? Or do I have a wrong perception?

If you refer to the [TextWebSocket Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol#text-websocket-messages) part of the document you posted. You can find the following statements:

> Text WebSocket messages carry a payload of textual information that consists of a section of headers and a body separated by the familiar double-carriage-return newline pair used for HTTP messages.

That means, the message you send to the service using `client.SendAsync()` can consists of two parts: the header part and the body part and two parts are separated by `double-carriage-return newline pair`.

> My second problem is WebSocketClient doesnt have any event handler to receive message

About this problem, you are doing it correctly,  you can try it again after you send the message correctly. The service will send back the words messages that it recognized.

Comment: i am using `Environment.NewLine;` for each every header i used, is it a correct `double-carriage-return newline pair` for C#?

Comment: I already update my Question a bit, does my headers code correct? Thank you for your time

Comment: I already update new codes that I have done (sending wav header and byte from audio), but I still doesn't receive any data. Did I call the DataReceiving wrong?

Comment: and also when I `SendAsync` some bytes, it get stucks after several sending (about 5-6).

`await _socketclient.SendAsync(byteresult, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, CancellationToken.None);
`.

Comment: Oops, i found that it's an error (Cannot access disposable object (the socket)), not stuck. sorry. It seems the connection got terminated?

Comment: There are three different types of messages [`speech.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol#message-speechconfig)(sent right after connection built).[`audio`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol#message-audio)(audio data) and [`telemetry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol#message-telemetry)(acknowledge the end of each turn). Did you send them correctly according to the doc?

Comment: Yes, i already sent speech.config after the connection, and then after that i sent audio wav header, then the audio stream for recording. What should I do for telemetry? I dont really get what the "turn" means.

Comment: Could you share your sample through online repo? You can remove your key and any other sensitive info from that.

Comment: I am sorry I don't think I can provide that now since my code is all mixed up with other stuff (in the project) and i need to clean it up, but anyway thanks for your response and it also seems that the connection is terminated because i send a wrong audio data format. I just have a little question, do I need to send telemetry? And what will it do? What's the function?

Comment: Referring to [telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol#message-telemetry) Clients must acknowledge the end of a turn by sending a telemetry message soon after receiving a `turn.end` message. So the `telemetry` message should be sent after you received a `turn.end` message. It is necessary.